# .net mvc partial view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

When creating partial views for .net mvc, does one have to create one for the edit action and the create action or one partial view is enough for both actions. Here I am considering views with dropdown lists, checkboxes, etc.

**Update 1**

Here is what I have been struggling with today:

I have a model with a couple of members and I have created the partial view as follows:

In the controller I have:

```
Public ActionResult trip()
{
  return View();
}
```

Inside the view folder (trip.cshtml):

```
@model tests.Models.Mission
<div id="contents">

<div class="editor-label">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tripName, "tripName")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.DropDownList("tripName", String.Empty)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tripName)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.giftname)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.giftname)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.giftname)
</div>
```

In the Edit Action:

I am loading the page using jQuery `load` method and it works ok for the Create action but for the Edit action, the data is not being loaded. I get a 404 error

```
$("#dynamicForm").load("/things/trip #contents", function(response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "";
                        $("#dynamicForm").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

And yes, I have tried `@Html.RenderPartial` and it works but this example I am trying to use jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by Edit action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single partial view if you want to, and bind it to your model. In the edit case it will be populated with data while in create mode it will bind to an empty model object.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your model. In most cases create/edit are based off the same model, so you should be able to reference one partial view...which makes it nice and DRY.

**Based on your update 1:**
I don't see where you are specifying which Mission object you are trying to edit in your $.load() call. I would imagine at the very least you'd want to pass a query string parameter like this: `/things/trip?mission=23`

Otherwise, your controller action has no clue which data to load into the view and send back in the response, and if you are getting a 404 error...make sure your path is correct to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a template.  It can be used with any action, so long as it does what you need it to.

The bigger issue is, does your edit and create require different templates due to their functionality?